# CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length - Retry in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, conda

I often get this error when building my conda env in a dockerfile.

`CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length`

In practice, I generally have to just re-run command and it will re-download the package and off it goes. Problem, docker just fails the build. Is there any sort of flag in Conda or Docker that says to re-try command? I guess if its docker, it would re-download everything and possibly cause error again, so really the fix should be via Conda or perhaps an Error check and retry and capture the failure in Docker so it doesn't "give up" and does re-try?

Answer (score 0):

it seems its a network issue and connection to google bucket. based on [this repo issue page](https://github.com/google/deepvariant/issues/228) you have to be sure you have access to google bucket from your docker